# How to truncate bash variable assignment without closing pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a way to limit the amount of data stored in a Bash variable that is initialised from the output of a sub-process.

Problem with this potential solution is that it stores the entire output before truncating it.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND_TO_RUN="du /"

OUT_DATA=$($COMMAND_TO_RUN)
OUT_RESULT=$?

if [[ $OUT_RESULT -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "${OUT_DATA:0:10000}" | head mail -s "Command failed" root@example.com
fi
```

Alternative `OUT_DATA=$($COMMAND_TO_RUN | head -c 10000)` cancels the command when the first 10k of output is read and I need the command to run to completion to capture its exit state.

I can do it quite easily in `python`, but am hoping for a `bash` only solution. And also without resorting to writing to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a function. For readability the below example hardcodes the command and such.

```
truncated_du() {
   du / | { head -c 10000; cat >/dev/null; }
   return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
}

out_data="$(truncated_du)"
out_result="$?"
```

`head` passes at most the desired amount of data to stdout of the function. If there is more data, `cat` will discard it without interrupting `du`. The exit status of `du` is retrieved from the `PIPESTATUS` array and returned by the function.

Note: my variables use `lower case`; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

---

Without a function the same solution looks like this:

```
out_data="$(
   du / | { head -c 10000; cat >/dev/null; }
   exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
)"
out_result="$?"
```

IMO it's little less readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

This limits the amount you capture, but I assume it exits with `read`s exit status (I don't know if it stops it stops the command like `head` would because the exit status is not respected: `

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -n $chars_to_capture foo < <($command)
```

It appears to let the command run to completion, but you don't get the command's exit status, you get `read`s exit status which is not helpful.

An example

```
$ IFS= read -r -d '' -n 19 foo < <(seq 50; touch somefile; exit 42); echo "exit=$?"; ls -l somefile
exit=0
-rw-r--r-- 1 glennjackman staff 0 Jul 22 22:04 somefile
```

I assume that the fact that the file is touched means that the command is not interrupted after the requested number of chars is captured.

Perhaps you could write the exit status to a file in the subshell:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -n 10000 out_data < <( $command_to_run; echo $? > statusfile )
if [[ -f statusfile ]] && [[ "$(<statusfile)" != "0" ]]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$out_data" | head mail -s "Command failed" root@example.com
    rm statusfile
fi
```